# Within the .tex file, a loop to compile to multiple PDFs recycling content according to language

Tags: pdftex, compiling, loops

I bet there are lots of loops using external processing, but I was hoping to get a preamble hack that would pdflatex out three outputs - suffixed according to Language selected -  of the following MWE:

(I use emacs With AUCTeX, maybe it is easier to customize a command from within there?)

```
% The following selects one langage. %
% What I _want_, is to automatically generate %
% from filename.tex three versions: 
% one English output to filename_english.pdf %
% and one in "norsk" and one in "nynorsk" named accordingly

\newcommand{\mylanguage}% To select language,
% uncomment precisely _one_ of the following:
% {english}%
{norsk}%
% {nynorsk}%


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,\mylanguage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,nynorsk,norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

{\protect\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{english}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{norsk}}{\selectlanguage{norsk}}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{nynorsk}}{\selectlanguage{nynorsk}}{}}}}

\newcommand{\ebn}[3]{\protect
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{english}}{#1}
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{norsk}}{#2}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{nynorsk}}{#3}}}{}}

\newcommand{\en}[2]{\ebn{#1}{#2}{#2}}


% lots of other preamble comments go in here.


\begin{document}
\hfill \emph{\ebn{English}{Bokmål}{Nynorsk}}

\ebn{Show that if}{Vis at hvis}{Vis at viss} $n^2$ \en{is odd,
  then}{er odde, er} $n$ \ebn{also is}{det også}{det òg}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably easier to have your IDE move each output PDF to the new name before processing the next round.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a shell script such as

```bsh
pdflatex -jobname multinils-english "\def\mylanguage{english}\input{multinils}"
pdflatex -jobname multinils-norsk "\def\mylanguage{norsk}\input{multinils}"
pdflatex -jobname multinils-nynorsk "\def\mylanguage{nynorsk}\input{multinils}"
```

where `multinils.tex` stands for the name of your LaTeX file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,\mylanguage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,nynorsk,norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

{\protect\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{english}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{norsk}}{\selectlanguage{norsk}}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{nynorsk}}{\selectlanguage{nynorsk}}{}}}}

\newcommand{\ebn}[3]{\protect
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{english}}{#1}
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{norsk}}{#2}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{nynorsk}}{#3}}}{}}

\newcommand{\en}[2]{\ebn{#1}{#2}{#2}}


% lots of other preamble comments go in here.


\begin{document}
\hfill \emph{\ebn{English}{Bokmål}{Nynorsk}}

\ebn{Show that if}{Vis at hvis}{Vis at viss} $n^2$ \en{is odd,
  then}{er odde, er} $n$ \ebn{also is}{det også}{det òg}.
\end{document}
```

Running the script will produce the three requested PDF files.